# UK: Can tradespeople park in a "permit holders only" residential area?

Tags: united-kingdom, parking

I am looking for a "buy to let" property in Nottingham. Most of the places I look at have "permit holders only" signs on the road. I am wondering how I am supposed to get tradespeople in to work on the property if they cannot park nearby.

Comment: FWIW most "permit holders only" schemes I've seen in the UK have "visitor" permits for just this sort of thing. Usually the householders on the road can get one or two such visitor permits in addition to their "resident" permit(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As these are "on the road" restrictions, I assume they fall within Nottingham City Council's [Parking Permit](https://www.nottinghamcity.gov.uk/residentpermit) scheme which states:

> Anyone who can prove they are a resident within a scheme area and are in an eligible property can apply for a Residents Permit.
>
> ...
>
> The maximum allocation of permits per household is 3 and this is made up of any combination of residents **or visitors permits**.
>
> ...
>
> **Vehicle specific Resident Permits require:**
>
> - A copy of the Motor Insurance Certificate (not required for visitor permits)
> - Residents living in a flat (i.e. a house converted into separate properties) will also be required to provide a water rates bill.

So, in answer to "*Can tradespeople park in a "permit holders only" residential area?*":

Yes, the solution is to have one or two visitors permits ready for use by tradespeople so they can park nearby (and not forgetting to get them back once the work is done as they cost £25 to replace).

**Edit to add the following**:

Nottingham also run a [Business Parking Permit](https://www.nottinghamcity.gov.uk/information-for-residents/transport-parking-and-streets/parking-and-permits/parking-permits/apply-for-a-business-parking-permit) scheme, and one would assume that Nottingham-based tradespeople would be aware of this and apply for their own permits.

Also, following @richardb's comment observing that the landlord may not be resident in the scheme's area so they won't be eligible for a Residents Permit, and assuming that the buy-to-let is run as a business ([most are](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/property-income-manual/pim2505)) then the Business Permit should be a viable option if they pay the fees and provide the following:

> - A copy of recent business rates or utility bill dated within the last 3 months containing the business name and address printed on them
> - Vehicle specific permits will also require a copy of the motor insurance certificate

Comment: It's not clear how/if you can obtain permits as a non-resident landlord. It might be worth OP asking.

Answer (score 0):

Operation of these parking schemes is up to the local council, for ordinary street parking. If it's a private car park then the owner of the car park makes the rules. Either way, the precise situation depends on whatever the local rules happen to allow. It's common for councils to offer a "business permit" for trades vehicles, which is for the business to acquire (i.e., not you). I don't think it's typical for property owners to have additional transferable permits for visitors, since as far as I know permits usually pertain to a specific vehicle, but councils will differ on what they offer.

If you're in an area with lots of parking restrictions of this kind, then local firms will be used to it. They are the ones who have to figure out whether to get a permit, or hoof their stuff down the road, or park anyway and chance it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "I don't think it's typical for property owners to have additional transferable permits for visitors": on the contrary, visitor permits of some form are not unusual. Where I live, residents can obtain a book of (non-transferable) visitor permits from the council.

Answer (score -1):

### Why do you care?

If you engage a contractor it’s their problem how they fulfill the contract.

Comment: If I engage a contractor to work on my home, surely it's in everyone's interest for me to make their life a bit easier if it doesn't cost me much effort, is it not? If they get a parking ticket, they may pass the cost on to me, or they may refuse to return for any future jobs, or they may just end up in a bad mood. If it costs me nothing to help, then why not do that?